# An error is displayed saying "NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity" when using tomcat 10 with hibernate 5.6

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

I have java project (version 8)

I upgraded my hibernate version from 5.0.3.Final to 5.6.9.Final

```
   <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.9.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.9.Final</version>
            </dependency>
```

I tried to run my tomcat (version 10.0.20) after upgrading the hibernate version and I received the next error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/db-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity (wrong name: jakarta/persistence/Entity)
```

The sessionFactory bean looks like that:

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
          depends-on="flyway">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="itpDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.imperva.itp.domain,com.imperva.itp.commons.domain"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect</prop>
                <prop key="configurationClass">org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${itp.db.username}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I don't know if it is relevant but my Spring version is 4.3.30.RELEASE

after running different combinations:

```
hibernate 5.0.3.Final with tomcat 8: works properly
hibernate 5.0.3.Final with tomcat 10: works properly
hibernate 5.6.9.Final with tomcat 8: works properly
hibernate 5.6.9.Final with tomcat 10: doesn't work and the exception is thrown
```

any ideas?

Comment: Check if you have other dependencies in the pom.xml that you must configure. For example there are <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> and <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId> related to hibernate.The error can be related to jakarta migration. Before it was javax. Maybe you use somewhere old version of dependency which is providing the javax but now you need jakarta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I upgraded the spring to 5.3.20 and spring web to 5.7.1 and I changed all the references of javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence and it worked. I kept the hibernate version 5.6.9.Final and tomcat 10

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 10 changed package names from javax to jakarta, the first Spring that will provide support for jakarta packages will be future Spring 6.

At the moment, and until further notice, Spring 5, or any version before will not be working with Tomcat 10.
So until Spring 6 is out, you should wait with the usage of Tomcat 10.

Tomcat 9 will work just fine for your needs.

Comment: so how is it possible that hibernate 5.0.3.Final with tomcat 10: works properly

Comment: I am not quite sure, it should not be possible as far as I know due to the package changes. The safest and the correct approach is to use Spring 5, Hibernate 5, and Tomcat 9 until all those 3 have stable versions with new jakarta packages.